# Streaming ipcam from Raspberry PI using Python/Flask

Tags: python, flask, stream, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I am trying to stream an internal IP Camera from home using Flask in a Raspberry PI (OS Raspbian).

In the Python side `cameras.py`, I used

```
from camera_pi import Camera
@app.route('/cameras/')
def index_cameras():
    """Video streaming home page"""
    return render_template('cameras.html')
```

and in the `cameras.hmtl` side I used

```
        <img src='http://192.168.10.1/videostream.cgi?stream=1'>
```

Inside my internal network, it worked perfectly. However, outside it does not stream. I am not allowed to use DDNS. Also, the requirement is that the streaming is handled by the Flask application.

How should I do this in order to stream to outside?

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to setup dynamic dns for your 192.168.10.1 device (or some device, say an always on PC, if it's behind the same router as the previously mentioned device) and open up firewall rules to communicate with your Dynamic DNS provider.

Once you have the dynamic dns URL, you'll need to replace your 192.168.10.1 URI with the one from your dynamic DNS in your cameras.html file.

Here's some instructions for rolling your own Dynamic DNS service using AWS:

http://willwarren.com/2014/07/03/roll-dynamic-dns-service-using-amazon-route53/

Comment: The requirement is that my Flask application handles the stream. If I could access http://192.168.10.1 using a DDNS it would be very easy, but it is not an option.